# laravel NotFoundHttpException appears though I have the function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have this code

```
<li>
    <a href="{{ URL::to('restaurants/admins/25') }}">
        <i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i> profile
    </a>
</li>
```

and in the routes, I have this:

```
Route::resource('restaurants', 'RestaurantsController');
```

but I got this error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
```

could you help please?

Comment: I think you need to tell us what you're trying to achieve, e.g. what does `admins` have to do with the rest of your code, what page are you hoping to link to.

Comment: @Unnawut I am trying to call the stated url but I got the stated exception

Comment: Yes but what `restaurants/admins/25` is supposed to do when you access it, what is the function/method that should be called, etc.

Comment: @Unnawut the restuarants is the controller, the admins is the function inside the controller so i am calling a function inside a controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

I would suggest you use url `restaurants/25/admins` instead of restaurants/admins/25 so that the entities are ordered from large to small, i.e. restaurants -> one restaurant -> restaurant's admin. So, for this answer I'm going to use:

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('restaurants/25/admins') }}">
```

Then in your route you can do:

```
Route::get('restaurants/{id}/admins'), 'RestaurantsController@admins');
Route::resource('restaurants', 'RestaurantsController');
```

And in controller code, you do:

```
class RestaurantsController
{
    // your code for index(), show(), etc...

    public function admins($id)
    {
        // Whatever you want Laravel to do for /restaurants/{id}/admins
    }
}
```

---

**Long answer:**

Let me explain a bit on what a `resource controller` does. In Laravel, when you do:

```
Route::resource('restaurants', 'RestaurantsController');
```

It is more or less a helper that automatically expands into these:

```
Route::get ('restaurants', 'RestaurantsController@index');
Route::get ('restaurants/{id}', 'RestaurantsController@show');
Route::get ('restaurants/create', 'RestaurantsController@create');
// There are a few more generated. See http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers
```

As you probably know, the first route is for displaying all restaurants. The second route is for displaying a specific restaurant. The third for displaying the form to add a restaurant.

One note is that Laravel merely generates those routes so you don't need to do write many routes over and over. What you write in the controller's methods (a.k.a. functions) depends totally on you. You could make your `/restaurants` show the form for adding restaurants, and `/restaurants/create` show the restaurants list. But that destroys the purpose of resource controllers because it's suppose to make you write code easier and shorter, while still being understandable!

So if we conform with what Laravel does. With this one-line route:

```
Route::resource('restaurants', 'RestaurantsController');
```

you get a url reserved for displaying all restaurants (`/restaurants`), another url for displaying a specific restaurant (`/restaurants/{id}`), and another url for the form to add a new restaurant (`/restaurants/create`). *Note: There are 7 routes but I'm mentioning only 3 here for brevity.*

If I understand correctly, what you are trying to do is to add another feature. You want a page that shows the list admins for a restaurant. That is something that does not fit the 3 urls we have yet, so you decided to create another one e.g. `restaurants/admins/25`.

My first recommendation to you is that, when structuring the url, try to arrange from the biggest entity to the smallest. Your original `restaurants/admins/25` translates roughly to:

> Restaurants > Admins of a restaurant > One restaurant

If I were you, I would go with something like this:

> Restaurants > One restaurant > Admins of a restaurant

So instead of restaurants/admins/25 my url would be:

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('restaurants/25/admins') }}">
```

Can you feel the difference? Now we have urls that are much more comprehensible:

```
restaurants               <-- show all restaurants
restaurants/25            <-- show restaurant #25
restaurants/25/admins     <-- show admins in restaurant #25
restaurants/create        <-- show form to create a new restaurant
```

Now your route file needs only an extra line to support `admins` which is our custom action:

```
Route::get('restaurants/{id}/admins'), 'RestaurantsController@admins');
Route::resource('restaurants', 'RestaurantsController');
```

And in controller code, you do:

```
class RestaurantsController
{
    // your code for index(), show(), etc...

    public function admins($id)
    {
        // Whatever you want Laravel to do for /restaurants/{id}/admins
    }
}
```

From here on, you can add `/restaurants/25/info`, `/restaurants/25/photos`, etc. as you like the same way as above.

Answer (score 0):

take `admins` out of your URL. It doesn't exist so it throws the exception.

So you want `URL::to('restaurants/25/show')` more than likely.

A helpful tip to visualize your routes, specifically Resourceful Controllers is to `artisan routes` in your console.

Comment: that is not a completely help solution, (i don't know if it is working bty) but maybe in the future, I needed a function like `restaruants/info/id`, i would be in a trouble

Comment: Well it either works or it doesn't. If you want a route like that just build it. Resourceful controllers are to be used in a certain way...you can't just hope they work how you want them. Use `artisan routes` to see how your Resource controller paths look and it will help you out.